# Mulitple compare conditions in a if statement in bash

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, compare

I want to put multiple compare conditions in a if statement using "or" operator
Here is the snippet.,

```
    if [[ "$input" == "string1" ] || [ "$input" == "string2" ] || [ "$input" == "string3" ]]; then
    ...
   fi
```

But when I execute the command, it fails saying syntax error near unexpected token `]'.

Could you guys please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
[[ .. ] || [ .. ] || [ .. ]]
```

by

```
[[ .. ]] || [[ .. ]] || [[ .. ]]
```

Comment: and, under the theory that less code is better code, you can do `if [[ "x" == "y" || "y" == "y" ]] ; then echo OK ; else echo nope ; fi` (in ksh at least). Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, You don't need extra `[` at first and last position in if condition.

```
if [ "$input" == "string1" ] || [ "$input" == "string2" ] || [ "$input" == "string3" ]; then
    ...
fi
```